# VHDL 8-bit counter

Tags: vhdl, counter, xilinx

I am a complete beginner in VHDL, so I was hoping that someone could help me with this project I am working on.

I need to realize rectangular pulse generator which frequency can be changed in the range 0 through 255. Frequency value in kHz must be shown binary on 8 LED diodes on the development board. For adjusting the output pulse frequency two buttons are used(incrementing/decrementing). When the button is held down for more than a second, the frequency is automatically incrementing/decrementing.

I wrote some code, but in Xilinx I get a ton of warnings. Can somebody explain them to me?

Code for frequency divider:

```
-- Frequency divider
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;


entity frequency_divider_15Hz is
port(
    cin : in std_logic;
    CLK : out std_logic
);
end frequency_divider_15Hz;


architecture behav_div of frequency_divider_15Hz is
    signal tmp : integer := 0;
    begin
process(cin)
    begin
    if (cin'event and cin = '1') then
        if (tmp < 800000)  then
                CLK <= '1';
                tmp <= tmp + 1;
        elsif (tmp < 1600000) then
                CLK <= '0';
                tmp <= tmp + 1;
        else
                CLK <= '0';
                tmp <= 0;
        end if;
    end if;
end process;
end behav_div;
```

Code for state machine:

```
-- State Machine
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
entity state_machine is
Port(
    CLK : in std_logic;
    RESET : in std_logic;
    U_D : in std_logic_vector (1 downto 0);
    frequency_output : out std_logic_vector (7 downto 0));
end state_machine;

architecture Behavioral of state_machine is
signal number : unsigned(7 downto 0) := "00000001";
signal direction : std_logic;
type state is (increment, decrement, restart, beginning, automatic);
signal next_state : state := beginning;
signal current_state : state := beginning;
signal counter1 : integer := 0;
signal counter2 : integer := 0;
begin

process (CLK)
begin
    if (CLK'event and CLK='1')then
        frequency_output <= std_logic_vector(number);
        case current_state is
            when increment =>
                if (number < "11111111") then
                    number <= number + 1;
                end if;
            when decrement =>
                if (number > "00000001") then
                    number <= number - 1;
                end if;
            when restart =>
                number <= "00000001";
            when automatic =>
                if (direction='1') then
                    if (number <"11111111") then
                        number <= number + 1;
                    end if;
                    elsif (direction = '0') then
                        if (number > "00000001") then
                            number <= number - 1;
                        end if;
                end if;
            when others =>
                    number <= number;
        end case;
        current_state <= next_state;
    end if;
end process;


process (current_state, U_D,RESET, CLK)
    begin
    case current_state is   
            when beginning =>
                    if (reset = '0') then
                        counter1 <= 0;
                        counter2 <= 0;
                        next_state <= restart;
                    elsif (CLK'event and CLK = '1') then
                        case U_D is
                            when "01" =>
                                    counter2 <= counter2 + 1;
                                    next_state <= beginning;
                            when "10" =>
                                    counter1 <= counter1 + 1;
                                    next_state <= beginning;
                            when "11" =>
                                if (counter2 > 0) then
                                    if (counter2 < 15) then
                                        counter2 <= 0;
                                        next_state <= increment;
                                    else
                                        direction <= '1';
                                        counter2 <= 0;
                                        next_state <= automatic;
                                    end if;
                                elsif (counter1>0) then
                                    if (counter1 < 15) then
                                        counter1 <= 0;
                                        next_state <= decrement;
                                    else
                                        direction <= '0';
                                        counter1 <= 0;
                                        next_state <= automatic;
                                    end if;
                                else
                                        counter1 <= 0;
                                        counter2 <= 0;
                                        next_state <= beginning;
                                end if;
                            when others =>
                                    next_state <= beginning;
                        end case;
                    end if;
            when automatic =>
                if (reset = '0') then
                    next_state <= restart;
                elsif (U_D(0) = '0') then
                    next_state <= beginning;
                elsif (U_D(1) = '0') then
                    next_state <= beginning;
                else
                    next_state <= automatic;
                end if;
            when increment =>
                next_state <= beginning;
            when decrement =>
                next_state <= beginning;
            when restart =>
                if (reset = '0') then
                    next_state <= restart;
                else
                    next_state <= beginning;
                end if;
            when others =>
                next_state <= beginning;
        end case;
end process;

end Behavioral;
```

Warnings:

```
WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <counter1<31>>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <counter1<30>>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <counter1<29>>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <counter1<28>>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <counter1<27>>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <counter1<26>>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <counter1<25>>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <counter1<24>>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <counter1<23>>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <counter1<22>>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <counter1<21>>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <counter1<20>>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <counter1<19>>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <counter1<18>>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <counter1<17>>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <counter1<16>>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <counter1<15>>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <counter1<14>>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <counter1<13>>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <counter1<12>>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <counter1<11>>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <counter1<10>>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <counter1<9>>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <counter1<8>>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <counter1<7>>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <counter1<6>>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <counter1<5>>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <counter1<4>>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <counter1<3>>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <counter1<2>>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <counter1<1>>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <counter1<0>>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <counter2<31>>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <counter2<30>>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <counter2<29>>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <counter2<28>>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <counter2<27>>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <counter2<26>>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <counter2<25>>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <counter2<24>>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <counter2<23>>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <counter2<22>>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <counter2<21>>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <counter2<20>>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <counter2<19>>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <counter2<18>>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <counter2<17>>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <counter2<16>>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <counter2<15>>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <counter2<14>>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <counter2<13>>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <counter2<12>>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <counter2<11>>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <counter2<10>>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <counter2<9>>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <counter2<8>>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <counter2<7>>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <counter2<6>>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <counter2<5>>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <counter2<4>>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <counter2<3>>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <counter2<2>>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <counter2<1>>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <counter2<0>>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <direction>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have one clocked process, and one unclocked process. The warnings are probably related to the unclocked process...

Comment: There was a recent question that had the same problem, but I can't seem to find it. You can't have a clocked portion of code embedded inside other logic in a process (i.e. in your "beginning" state) - it's not valid synthesis style. There may be other problems as well.

Comment: There's a set of registers on the frequency_output that you may not have intended or need, the assignment from number occurring in a clocked process.

Answer (score 3):

The second process of your state machine is the culprit. A process should be either synchronous or combinational, not a mix of both.

A synchronous process has this form:

```
process(reset, clk)
begin
    if (reset = '0' then
        signals <= reset_value;
    elsif (clk'event and clk = '1') then
        *logic here*
    end if;
end process;
```

Combinational processes **do not** use reset or clk. When using combinational processes, make sure all signals are assigned in every paths, i.e. every if has an else, every case an others. Failing to assign a signal in one of the paths will yield a latch.

Latches are evil's incarnation to anyone but experts. Any design using latches will most likely not behave the same on hardware as it does on simulation.

Comment: Your presented process example is not synchronous because it uses an asynchronous reset ...

Comment: That's a bit nitpicky. A register with an asynchronous reset is still a synchronous element.